# activeTab not working with webRequest in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here's the code (in my background script) giving me problems:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener((details) => {
    if(details.type == "main_frame"){
        randomname(details.url);
    }
},{urls: ["http://*/*","https://*/*"]},["responseHeaders"]);
```

Here's the permissions from my `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "unlimitedStorage"]
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCompleted' of undefined
```

The error goes away when I change my permissions to this:

```
"permissions": ["webRequest", "activeTab", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage", "unlimitedStorage"]
```

I don't understand why I have to specify `webRequest` and hosts in my permissions.  According to the [activeTab documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab), I should technically be able to...

*"Intercept network requests in the tab to the tab's main frame origin using the webRequest API. The extension temporarily gets host permissions for the tab's main frame origin."*

Additionally, their example uses `activeTab` without declaring `webRequest` in the permissions.

Comment: This won't work. As you can see in the documentation `activeTab` grants access only to code that was executed by a user gesture. For example, you can register a new webRequest listener inside a click/hotkey event so it'll work for the current tab.

Comment: Then is there no alternative to monitor what URL a user is viewing without causing the permissions message "has access to read and change all your data"?  Because anytime I add webRequest I get that message...

Comment: You can use chrome.tabs.onUpdated.